# API monitoring using splunk

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I have one API : `[GET] http:localhost:8080/myservice/fetchdetails`.
Now, I want to raise splunk alert whenever this API is down for any reason.

So, I have my search query as `|eval ['http:localhost:8080/myservice/fetchdetails'] | search status=20*` to monitor the API.

But it is not fetching me any result. What should be the search query such that it makes a get call to the API and then capture the response status?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? What does your data look like?

Comment: @warren: I am trying to call a get API and check the status of the API, and subsequently trigger an alert based upon the status.

Comment: that...doesn't really explain _at all_ what you're trying to do. What does your data look like? What API are you trying to use? What have you tried? Elaborate your *whole* use case into the question, complete with what you've tried, sample data, and expected output.

Comment: @warren: the response data is a JSON. Primarily , I am trying to make a get call from the search query and capture the result, then raise a splunk alert  on filtering the result.

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your expanded question, you're going to need to actually *get* that REST endpoint's data into Splunk

There are at least two ways to do this

First - use the [REST API Modular Input](https://splunkbase.splunk.com/app/1546) and ingest data from the endpoint. If you don't get data within some timeframe...send an Email.

Second - create your own [scripted input](https://docs.splunk.com/Splexicon:Scriptedinput) that periodically hits your endpoint (maybe with [wget](/questions/tagged/wget) or [curl](/questions/tagged/curl)), and reports an HTTP status code into Splunk. Your Alert can then check to see if the code isn't 200 (or whatever else you want to consider "valid"). If it's "invalid", send an email.

Answer (score 0):

The `eval` command assigns a value to a field, therefore it must be in the form `<field> = <expression>`.  The sample query just has the expression.

An SPL (Search Processing Language) query must begin with the `search` command (usually implicit) or a `|` followed by a generating command.

Tell us more about the problem you are trying to solve and we may be able to suggest a query to help solve it.

Comment: I am trying to call a get API and check the status of the API, and subsequently trigger an alert based upon the status.

Comment: That doesn't give us much to work with.  Can you share more details?

Comment: I have edited my question for more clarity. Primarily , I am trying to make a get call from the search query and capture the result, then raise a splunk alert on filtering the result.

Answer (score 0):

Its simple just work on the Base query and put your base query and use below format

Base query status!=20* OR Status!=30* earliest=-10m| bin _time span=5m |stats count by status _time| where count>1